# How I can change display name for property in metadata class in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustMetadata))]
public partial class Customer { }

public class CustMetadata
{
    [Display(Name="FFFF")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

i need to change name from FFFF To another name dynamic at runtime

Comment: Attributes cannot be changed at runtime, they are part of the `Type`.

Comment: To what end? Does this mean your CompanyName property will not always be that? Or are you trying to translate it?